# How to set specific date with WPF date picker in Robot Framework using White Library

Tags: wpf, automation, robotframework, white-framework

I am working on a WPF application and writing automation tests using **White library** in **RIDE**. For test automation I am using **Robot Framework**. I am very new to Robot Framework and White.

I am unable to find any way to select date in WPF date picker control in White. I have looked over many places for the solution but could not found the answer for my problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the source code of what you've tried and the results you've observed?

Comment: Did you solve this?